# Change Excel Worksheet background colour based on values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

Hopefully some one can help, but not sure if its possible. I'm using Excel 2010.

I want to change the background colour of a **whole** worksheet to green if the value in cell c20 is equal to or greater than the value in cell C21.

Any help would be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: You don't list VBa as an option and it may have to be... There *appears* to be no way to do this directly. Or do you really not want VBa?

Comment: Under what circumstance would you like to change the color of all the cells? When and how does the cell get updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select all cells on the sheet
2. Go to "Conditional Formatting" -> "New Rule..."
3. Under "Select a Rule Type:", select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
4. In the box below "Format values where this formula is true:", type in `=$C$20>=$C$21`
5. Then click on the "Format" button to choose which styling you wish to apply. For background colour, go to the "Fill" tab.

Note: these steps apply to Excel 2007 but should be mostly similar in Excel 2010.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for your help, really appreciate it!